# how can i select the any changes in on column?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
state         date
new           01/01/2018
new           02/01/2018
active        05/01/2018
active        09/01/2018
active        10/01/2018
new           12/01/2018
active        13/01/2018
active        14/01/2018
close         15/01/2018
```

and I need to any change in state column whit the min date of each category.

final table:

```
state         date
new          01/01/2018
active       05/01/2018
new          12/01/2018
close        15/01/2018
```

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: Do you actually want to delete (=physically remove) those rows from the table. Or just a query that returns the result you want, but leaves the data in the table?

Comment: Do the `Group by state` and with that `SELECT MIN(date)` assuming you mean you want to get that as resultset. Also I am assuming `date` is `datetime` type column

Comment: There is the way @CoderofCode stated which is the easiest. There are alternatives such as row number functions or similar.

Comment: when i group by with state i lose the second new

Comment: @navidkarampour your criteria isn't clear why should second new get selected and why not second active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't tagged any DBMS, so i would go with `row_number()` as it seem `gaps-and-islands` issue :

```
select state, min(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seq1,
             row_number() over (partition by state order by date) as seq2
      from table t
      ) t
group by state, (seq1-seq2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using WITH and LAG

```
WITH state_change (state, st_date, next_state) AS
  (SELECT state , st_date, 
          LAG(state, 1, '') OVER(ORDER BY st_date) as s2
   FROM table
 )
SELECT state, st_date
FROM state_change
WHERE state != next_state
ORDER BY st_date ASC
```

Output (that includes the second change to active)

```
state   st_date
new     2018-01-01
active  2018-01-05
new     2018-01-12
active  2018-01-14
close   2018-01-15
```

Comment: tax veryyyy much  .